# Angular 2 EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I just follow the tutorial of using InMemoryBackendService to mock server. However, I got this error and don't know why.

This is '/app/job/job-page.ts'

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {JobService} from './job-service';
import {Job} from './model/job';

@Component({
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ],
  selector: '[job-page]',
  host: {
    class: 'job-page app'
  },
  template: require('./job-page.html'),
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./job-page.scss'), require('./login-page.scss')],
  providers: [JobService]
})

export class JobPage {

  public job: Job;
  constructor(private jobService: JobService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getJob();
  }

  getJob(){
    this.jobService.getJob().then((job) => {
      this.job = job;
      console.log(job);
    })
  }
}
```

This is file '/app/job-service.ts'

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Job } from '../job-list-page/job';

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


@Injectable()
export class JobService{

    private jobUrl = './app/job-page/job';

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    getJob(): Promise<Job> {
        return this.http.get(this.jobUrl)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then((response) => response.json().data)
                        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
      return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

This is file 'app/job-page/job-data.ts'

```
export class JobData {
  createDb() {
    let job = [
      { id: '1', name: 'Windstorm' },
      { id: '2', name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: '3', name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: '4', name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return {job};
  }
}
```

This is the console.log:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
browser_adapter.ts:78EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefinedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.ts:78
browser_adapter.ts:78TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at InMemoryBackendService.parseId (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:146311:37)
    at InMemoryBackendService.handleRequest (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:146137:23)
    at InMemoryBackendService.createConnection (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:146095:25)
    at httpRequest (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:78654:21)
    at Http.get (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:78703:17)
    at JobService.getJob (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:211008:27)
    at JobPage.getJob (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:210956:26)
```

I think my codes are right. I follow the tutorial step by step. Just don't know what is the problems of my code.

Comment: What is the content of the template `job-page.html`?

Answer (score 2):

Very likely, you are using result of `JobService.getJob()` before the `Promise` has been resolved.

The code of the template is missing from your question, but I'm guessing, you access non-existing element in template

Comment: I've checked that I use {{job?.title}} to avoid using the variable before Promise has been resolved. Still can't find where the problem is : (

Answer (score 1):

```
....
@Injectable()
    export class JobService{
    private jobUrl = './app/job-page/job';
....
```

According to https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/src/in-memory-backend.service.ts

> Expect URI pattern in the form :base/:collectionName/:id?

Try to modify your url to

```
private jobUrl = 'api/job';
```

Comment: @gogopower can you mark this question as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change jobUrl to 'app/job-page/job' or it might be just 'app/job' I can't remember exactly how the mock back end looks up the data - Though I am fairly sure it the the latter... 'app/job'